# Structured logging with Common.Logging and NLog

Tags: c#, nlog, common.logging, structured-logging

I have the latest version of [Common.Logging](https://github.com/net-commons/common-logging) (3.4.1) and [NLog](https://nlog-project.org/) (4.5.11) in my project. Instructions were followed to tie up Common.Logging with NLog in the app.config, and logging now works.

Now I want to have structured logging:

```
private static readonly ILog _logger = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

var message = new IDontKnowWhat("A structured message for ClientId {ClientId}", ClientId.ToString());
_logger.Info(message);
```

The above is pseudo code, I do not know how to construct the message object.
And, *_logger.InfoFormat* seems to work with *String.Format*, instead of structured logging.

Does [Common.Logging](https://github.com/net-commons/common-logging) provide for structured logging, besides using *ThreadVariablesContext/GlobalVariablesContext/NestedThreadVariablesContext*?

Comment: Think you are waiting for this issue: https://github.com/net-commons/common-logging/issues/159 (Sadly enough fixing this will be a "breaking" change as Common-Logging for some reason tries to perform the parsing and formatting, instead of letting the logging framework do the job). SerilogLogger performs a hack to work-around the restrictions of the Common-Logging-Framework, so can work with structured-logging.

Comment: It seems so indeed.. I am now trying LibLog as we speak. I have structured logging working with the LibLog/NLog combination, only having problems displaying the info I pass in via OpenMappedContext.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Luckily for me, the Common.Logging development team is currently fixing this:
[Common.Logging.NLog45 with support for structured logging #176](https://github.com/net-commons/common-logging/pull/176)

Answer (score 1):

Checkout [serilog](https://github.com/serilog/serilog) to have structured logging. If your requirements is to use NLog, serilog also has a sink to NLog.

Comment: My requirement is to use Common.Logging with structured logging. If there are any good examples of Common.Logging with Serilog, I can try that. I'd be happier when I can get it to work with NLog, so I don't have to reconfigure all my app domains.

Comment: If it helps, there's example Common.Logging + Serilog info in: https://github.com/CaptiveAire/Common.Logging.Serilog#readme